# Is there an advantage to purchasing a domain from a broker that's in "Pending Delete" status?

Tags: domain-registration

I had a domain which I let it go. It's current status is "*Pending Delete*".

Ever since it entered into *Redemption Period* I've been getting emails from a domain broker for buying this domain, since I own an (expired) `.org` version of same domain.

**I hope it will be available soon to everybody and I can buy it directly, but what is the advantage in going through them?**

Here is the email from the broker:

> Hi,
>
> We just wanted to let you know that domain EXAMPLE.COM is being
>   released back to the market.
>
> Since you own EXAMPLE.ORG, we believe that you might have interest in
>   securing EXAMPLE.COM as well.
>
> If you are interested, please CLICK ON THIS LINK to get more
>   information and confirm your interest.
>
> All the additional information is available on our web site, but feel
>   free to reply back to this email and we will be more than happy to
>   help you.
>
> Kind regards,
>
> Domain Brokers Team

Comment: This is very common. There are lists of expiring domains, and a simple lookup for the name with different extensions can be automated to send out these solicitations. It just so happened that you are the current registrant of the `.com` as well, until it's deleted. If you're still interested in the domain, I'd recommend contacting the registrar to see if they'll still allow you to pay the redemption fee. If not, then backordering it with a reputable service would be wise. At this point, there's no advantage going through the broker, since they can only backorder it too, once you show interest.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common for this sort of thing to happen. As @dan says there are lists of expiring domains available and these brokers make a business model out of going through the expiring domains lists and finding registrants of the same domain under a different TLD's under the premis that the registrant may want to purchase the additional domain to secure their brand and prevent someone from opening up the same domain name under a different TLD in direct competition. Unfortunately often these brokers charge significantly more than going direct through a reputable registry and so it is often not economic to use them as they are rarely registries in their own right and often simply purchase the domains from an ICANN accredited registry anyway, which you are able to do yourself for close to the same price as they would be able to do.

As @dan says if you where the former owner of the domain name and you are still in the redemption period you have the option of contacting your original registry and seeing if they would allow you to still pay for the domain to make it active again, and many will do so. Failing that you can backorder the domain so that once the redemption period ends and the domain comes back on the market you are able to purchase it again and you can do this through your chosen registry as many registries have backordering available.

I can't stress enough that it is always best to go through reputable registry and not through a brokerage company as you will get the best costs and service through the registry and many registries are ICANN accredited and so bound to ICANN rules whereas the brokers are no different to any other companies out there that register domains for themselves and so are not bound by the same rules.